# CKEditor not working after server upgrade

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

After server upgrade from Domino 8.5.3 to 9.0.1FP2, the CKEditor in one of our applications stopped working but only on a few PC's. Some users see the full CKEditor in that appliacation some users don't. All of them have the same browsers (Firefox and IE) in the same versions.

Those, who does not see that CKEditor, see only a simple TextArea on it's place.

Has anybody any idea, where could be a problem?

Thanks, JiKra

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the browser cache in order for the updated CKEditor files to be downloaded (and used).

There's a similar discussion on my blog at http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2014/08/xpages-and-domino-9-0-1-fp2-upgrades-to-ckeditor-and-dojo.html.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning and rebuilding the application worked for us.