# Domino 9.01 FixPack 4 CKEditor error

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

We've upgraded our Domino Server to FP4 and since then we are facing some issues regarding RichText-Fields. Those fields seem to be broken and can not be loaded. This leads to the problem, that on some pages our buttons do not work as long as there is a RichText-Field.

Our field looks like this (no actions):

[image]

I'm already using this field in an empty Xpage with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
      <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
         <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
               <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
            </xp:this.action>
         </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:button>
      <xp:br></xp:br>
      <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"></xp:inputRichText>
   </xp:view>
```

But also on this simple page the field does not work and the code of the button does not work either. I can only see this error in the browser console:

[image]

But I don't know what exactly causes this problem? On some of your databases everything works fine, but with others we have this shown effect. I know that this seems to be an issue with FP4, but I could not find any solution for our problem yet.

I've already disabled "runtime optimized JS and CSS", with no effect.

So can anybody give me a hint here?

Comment: Does it still fail if you clear your browser cache (in order for the browser to re-download the CKEditor files)?

Comment: It does. We've cleared the cache (F5, STRG + F5, STRG + R) also also set the browser back to standard. Nothing worked

Comment: Try disabling resource aggregation so that all JS and CSS files are loaded seperately

Comment: That's the solution! Please create an answer to this question so that I can accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try enabling resource aggregation again and see if it now works. I still think it's a caching issue

Comment: You're right. Now it even works with the resource aggregation enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domino 9.0.1 FP4 contains an update to CKEditor (to version 4.4.3). You need to refresh the browser cache in order for the updated CKEditor files to be downloaded (and used).

Here's a similar question and answer for FP2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28092593/785061